# Javascript overflow in a widget in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using the plugin Enhanced Text Widget in WordPress to display Javascript in a sidebar widget. The script runs and displays the info, but the content overflows outside the widget area. I want to keep the content within the confines of the widget area and I've tried a few different CSS options and nothing is working to contain it.

Site is: http://dev.northwestfiretraining.com/ and its on the left sidebar under DAILY BURN INFO.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your css needs to be tweaked.

The .burn class is too wide, with a width set fixed to 320px, instead of dynamic based on the width of the container div (.textwidget):

```
    .burn {
        width: 320px;
        background: url(images/burn_status_bkgrd.png) center no-repeat;
        height: 250px;
    }
```

Try changing it to this:

```
    .burn {
        width: 100%;
        background: url(images/burn_status_bkgrd.png) center no-repeat;
        height: 250px;
    }
```

Comment: Ah ok. Is that CSS within the script? Cause that CSS is not within the site content. Sorry I'm fairly new to scripting and this script is not something I created.

Comment: Is there any way to override the CSS in the script with CSS from the site? I've used !important and that doesn't work.

Comment: It says when I inspect that it's in the <style> </style> tags - Directly above the burn div - maybe check in the widget source.

<div class="textwidget widget-text">
 <script...></script>
 <style type="text/css">
  #fa-burn-status-display {text-align: center;font-size: 12px;padding-top:5px;}
  .burn {width: 320px;background: url(images/burn_status_bkgrd.png) center no-repeat;height:250px;}
  #fa-page-view-ag {background-color: #ccc;}.spaced ul, .spaced ol { margin-top:1em;padding-top:1em; list-style-position: inside;}
  .spaced li { margin-bottom:1em;padding-bottom:1em; }
 </style>

Answer (score 0):

```
.burn
{
width: auto !important;
}
```

Add this code in your style.